# Delete bulk item in doctrine zend framework 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to allow `bulk item delete` in my ZF2 project.

I am using doctrine.

I don't know how to pass bulk item to the delete action.

How do I pass all item id to the controller, to be able to delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement bulk delete by few different ways:

**1) Using DQL**

```
<?php
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$query = $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM App\\Entity\\User u WHERE u.id IN (:ids)');
$query->setParameter('ids', $ids);
$query->execute();
```

**2) Iterating results**

```
<?php
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$users = $em->getRepository('App\\Entity\\User')->findById($ids);
foreach($users as $user) {
   $em->remove($user);
}
$em->persist();
```

**3) Batch Processing**

```
<?php
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM App\\Entity\\User u');
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
    $em->remove($row[0]);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all deletions.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
    ++$i;
}
$em->flush();
```

**Update**

Lets assume we have the following uri: &ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
so, you can get the ids in the controller:

```
<?php
class UserController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function deleteAction() 
    {
        $query = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();

        $users = $em->getRepository('App\\Entity\\User')->findById($query['ids']);
        foreach($users as $user) {
             $em->remove($user);
        }
        $em->persist();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, and FYKI I am using approach 2 at the moment. But how do I pass those $ids from view file? That's the problem I am facing.